# Get notified about comment replies via Instagram Graph API Web Hooks

Tags: javascript, .net, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

In our solution we would like to get notified about new replies to an already existing comment. After investigating the Meta Developer Docs, we've figured out that we could use web hooks to get informed regarding new comments, however replies to existing comments were not explicitly mentioned. Trying it out requires our Instagram App to be verified during a review. That way we simply could try it out. Unfortunately our solution is still under development hence a review comes a little too early.

Do you know if it's possible to use web hooks in order to get notified about new comment replies?